# FFT implementation

Tags: java, fft

I am working on application to enhance an image using `FFT`.

I have implemented the code for `FFT`:

[image]

For the first formula in above picture i have implemented code as below :

```
  void fft(int x , int y , int size) {
    
    for(int i=x; i<x+32 ; i++){
        for(int j=y ; j<y+32 ; j++){
            double kth = -2 * Math.PI * (((i*x)/size)+((j*y)/size));
            ComplexNumber expo = new ComplexNumber(Math.cos(kth),Math.sin(kth));
            output.values[i][j] = ComplexNumber.cMult(input.values[x][y],expo) ;
            intermediate.values[i][j] = output.values[i][j];
            input.values[i][j] = output.values[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I have also implemented code for second and third formula but the result I am getting is not correct.
What should I do ?

Is the code implemented for the first equation correct?

**Edited**

Basically I want to do image enhancement with FFT.I found the formula which I have already posted above.I have also implemented the code for those formulas.But I am not yet clear with all the variables used in that formula.Can any one please explain in detail all the variables used in that formula like M & N,as they have given the for u & v.